# create polygon with a hole as Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY from two circle geometries

Tags: oracle, geometry, oracle10g, oracle-spatial

In the example given in Oracle Docs, there is a way to create a polygon with a hole with the following syntax:

```
SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2003,  -- two-dimensional polygon
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1, 19,2003,1), -- polygon with hole
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(2,4, 4,3, 10,3, 13,5, 13,9, 11,13, 5,13, 2,11, 2,4,
        7,5, 7,10, 10,10, 10,5, 7,5)
  )
```

In my case, I have two SDO_GEOMETRY created as follows:

```
SELECT sdo_util.circle_polygon (longitude_1,
                                latitude_1,
                                r_1,                                         
                                tol)
           INTO inner_circle_geom
           FROM DUAL;


SELECT sdo_util.circle_polygon (longitude_2,
                                latitude_2,
                                r_2,                                         
                                tol)
           INTO outer_circle_geom
           FROM DUAL;
```

How can I create the polygon with a hole using the two geometries above?

I've tried using

```
...
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(outer_circle_geom.sdo_ordinates, inner_circle_geom.sdo_ordinates)
```

But I receive the error

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY'
```

EDIT: the Oracle version is 10g

Comment: Have you tried [`SDO_GEOM.SDO_XOR`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geom-sdo_xor.htm#SPATL1128) or [`SDO_GEOM.SDO_DIFFERENCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geom-sdo_difference.htm#SPATL1115)?

Comment: @MT0 do you mean that you suggest to use SDO_XOR or SDO_DIFFERENCE with the circles as parameters instead of geometry creation listed above (polygon with a hole)?

Comment: That was my thought. I don't use Oracle spatial so I don't quite know how to implement it. I started with [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d25605ca709208d90825fcf4e0f84b4e) but there is something wrong somewhere and I don't know if its the generation of the shapes or something I haven't set up correctly in the co-ordinate systems or if its just the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MT0's thought is right. You can use `select sdo_geom.sdo_difference(`
`sdo_util.circle_polygon (longitude_2, latitude_2,r_2, tol),`
`sdo_util.circle_polygon (longitude_1, latitude_1,r_1, tol), tol)`
`from dual;`

Answer (score 0):

You can define it by hand using the element info:

- with the `SDO_ETYPE` of `1003` and `SDO_INTERPRETATION` of `4` to define the exterior circle using three points on the circumference; and
- with the `SDO_ETYPE` of `2003` and `SDO_INTERPRETATION` of `4` to define the interior circle using three points on the circumference.

For example, if you want two concentric circles centred at 0,0 with an exterior radius of 10 and an interior radius of 5 then:

```sql
SDO_GEOMETRY(
  2003, -- In the format D0XX where D is the number of dimensions and
        -- an XX value of 03 is a polygon (with or without holes)
  NULL,
  NULL,
  SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(
     1,    -- offset for the first ordinate of this element
     1003, -- this element is an exterior polygon ring 
     4,    -- which is a circle defined by 3 points on the circumference
     
     7,    -- offset for the first ordinate of this element
     2003, -- this element is an interior polygon ring
     4     -- which is a circle defined by 3 points on the circumference
  ),
  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(
    10.00,   0.00, -- first point on exterior circle
     0.00,  10.00, -- second point on exterior circle
   -10.00,   0.00, -- third point on exterior circle

     5.00,   0.00, -- first point on interior circle
     0.00,  -5.00, -- second point on interior circle
    -5.00,   0.00  -- third point on interior circle
  )
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=218e2886f47d74cf8d641b5cdaaa8963)*

Comment: it does not solve the issue. here you gave an SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY() with given points, but I want to create the SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY from two SDO_GEOMETRY elements